# Bluetooth Adapter not found on Linux Mint

Tags: linux-mint, bluetooth, bluez, blueman

I have an HP Pavilion-15 laptop with Linux Mint and Windows in dual boot config and have been having bluetooth issues for a long while. Off-late my PC has been unable to detect any Bluetooth adapter at all. I have tried everything, looked into multiple forums, but no avail.

A screengrab of blueman after I click on Adapters option is shown here:

[image: screengrab]

I uninstalled and reinstalled bluez, installed blueman, but to no avail. Some of the outputs of the things I tried are below:

- `hcitool dev` gives no bluetooth device. Neither do any other hci commands.
- `bluetoothctl` outputs are here:

  ```
  Agent registered
  [bluetooth]# show
  No default controller available
  [bluetooth]#
  ```
- `rfkill` does not list bluetooth
- `systemctl bluetooth status` output

  ```
  bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
  Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset
  Active: active (running) since Mon 2021-12-27 16:03:21 IST; 4h 30min ago
  Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
  Main PID: 3411 (bluetoothd)
  Status: "Running"
   Tasks: 1 (limit: 4915)
  CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
          └─3411 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd

  Dec 27 16:03:21 prabodh-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs1xxx systemd[1]: Starting Blueto
  Dec 27 16:03:21 prabodh-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs1xxx bluetoothd[3411]: Bluetooth
  Dec 27 16:03:21 prabodh-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs1xxx systemd[1]: Started Bluetoo
  Dec 27 16:03:21 prabodh-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs1xxx bluetoothd[3411]: Starting 
  Dec 27 16:03:21 prabodh-HP-Pavilion-Laptop-15-cs1xxx bluetoothd[3411]: Bluetooth
  ```

I did a Bluetooth service restart using `systemctl`, did not work.

- `sudo lsmod | grep blue` output:

  ```
  bluetooth             544768  10 btrtl,btintel,btbcm,bnep
  ecdh_generic           16384  1 bluetooth
  ```
- `dmesg | grep -i blue` output

  ```
  [   18.846174] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
  [   18.846203] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
  [   18.846205] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
  [   18.846206] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
  [   18.846208] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
  [  115.866301] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
  [  115.866303] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
  [  115.866309] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
  [  384.520506] audit: type=1400 audit(1640601469.856:29): apparmor="STATUS"    operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.bluetooth-autostart" pid=5349 comm="apparmor_parser"
  [  384.577833] audit: type=1400 audit(1640601469.912:30): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluetooth-autostart.autostart-bluetooth" pid=5350 comm="apparmor_parser"
  [  401.660520] audit: type=1400 audit(1640601486.984:33): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" profile="unconfined" name="snap.bluetooth-autostart.autostart-bluetooth" pid=5386 comm="apparmor_parser"
  [  401.662906] audit: type=1400 audit(1640601486.988:34): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" info="same as current profile, skipping" profile="unconfined" name="snap-update-ns.bluetooth-autostart" pid=5388 comm="apparmor_parser"
  [  410.729139] audit: type=1400 audit(1640601496.048:35): apparmor="DENIED" operation="create" profile="snap.bluetooth-autostart.autostart-bluetooth" pid=5413 comm="hciconfig" family="bluetooth" sock_type="raw" protocol=1 requested_mask="create" denied_mask="create"
  ```

  Note: I installed `bluetooth-autostart` snap after trying a lot of other things. Before that, the `dmesg` output was whatever is in the snippet above apart from the snap related messages.
- The output of `lscpi` does not seem to list a bluetooth i/f

  ```
  00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 3e34 (rev 0b)
  00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 3ea0
  00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th    Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0b)
  00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df9 (rev 30)
  00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 9ded (rev 30)
  00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 9def (rev 30)
  00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 9df0 (rev 30)
  00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 9de0 (rev 30)
  00:17.0 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 30)
  00:19.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9dc5 (rev 30)
  00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db8 (rev f0)
  00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9dbc (rev f0)
  00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db0 (rev f0)
  00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9db1 (rev f0)
  00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9d84 (rev 30)
  00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 9dc8 (rev 30)
  00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 9da3 (rev 30)
  00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 9da4 (rev 30)
  02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP108M [GeForce MX150] (rev a1)
  04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
  ```
- On Windows, I am able to detect and connect the bluetooth devices normally. in fact, I have a feeling that the issues started after I booted into Windows once. I disabled fast boot on windows and did a cold restart. Did not resolve.

I am at the end of my rope here. Please suggest something to resolve this issue. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

I see that the module btusb is not showing in the lsmod.
Try `sudo modprobe btusb`

Answer (score -1):

try this: `sudo systemctl enable bluetooth.service` (make sure you have installed bluetooth package)